# HTTP Request in Swift with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to make an HTTP Request in an iOS app with Swift using NSURLSession, but XCode throws an error. I've been searching all over stackoverflow and the web and my code is pretty similar to what people suggested, but for some reason it doesn't work. I am on XCode 6.0.1 (6A317).

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(url),
    completionHandler : {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        println("Done")
})
session.resume()
```

The error points to the first line above: "*Extra argument 'completionHandler' in call*"

Using Trailing Closure throws a similar error:

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(url)) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
    println("Done")
}
session.resume()
```

The error is also on the first line: "*Extra argument in call*"

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I found out where the error is.
The problem's not with the `NSURLSession()`, but with `NSURL()`

```
NSURL(string: url)
```

Error's now gone.

Answer (score 3):

Simple get request would be like this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "url_here")) { data, response, error in
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Where do the `data`, `response` and `error` get value from? Are they outputs that are captured by the closure? How do those parameters get their values?

Comment: Those values are passed by the NSURLSession to closure

Comment: Obviously! I am asking how! You aren't using it with the `completionhandler` keyword[this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:)... you are only using `dataTaskWithURL(_:)` meaning you shouldn't receive any parameters

Comment: It is just sample code. For your real application you need to use those values. Perhaps I should add comment line inside closure that says use your response here

Comment: What do you mean it's a sample code? It can be used just as you wrote it. see [here](https://youtu.be/m6yUyriBl9c?t=112). Do you mind adding more explanation to your answer?